# Using getResources().getString inside a DialogFragment - crash

Tags: android, string, android-dialogfragment

I have Dialogs shown when I start the App (the class is used from MainActivity). I want to use a string from strings.xml but when I use getResources().getString(R.string.stringname) it crashes the app, giving the error that it is not attached to the activity. How do I fix this?

Comment: Post the logcat and some code so that we can help you

Comment: can we see ur logcat..

Answer (score 1):

You should use ApplicaitonContext,simple as:
MiyaApplication.getApplication().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.loading);

Answer (score 0):

I if you have got the error saying that `"dialog is not attached to the activity"`, I think the problem is not with the string resource.

It is mostly possible that you are showing a dialog from a background service. You can not simply show a normal dialog with application context instance. You need a activity window to hold your dialog.

However, if you really need to show dialog from background service (no activity of your application), you should use **dialog styled activity**.

Put this property in your activity section of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```